# How do you determine if a compound can go through addition polymerisation

Tags: polymers

[image]

For a polymer to form from a monomer, the monomer requires open bonds to attach itself to another monomer. Logically for me, it requires a double bond so I would go for answer C. But can the benzene ring actually open up to undergo an addition polymerisation?

Comment: What do you think?

Comment: I think the question in the picture could use one additional letter.

Comment: Hint: Benzene has a delocalized electron cloud which is not *exactly* equivalent to a double bond.

Comment: hint: basically all polymerisation reactions are exergonic. Would that apply for C? (And would it for A, btw.?)